# How do you make a button half of the usable viewport's height?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I'm making an app for people to learn Japanese (without having to pay to learn more like the rest) so I can understand the ins and outs of Xcode & Swift 3.

The original plan was to have the initial view being two buttons that take up half of the viewport.

I set the buttons to be equal heights to the View and gave them a multiplier of .5, but when stacked on top of each other, the second button extends past the bottom of the screen (as shown below).

[image: Those buttons I talked about..]

It all seems to nail down to the status bar being involved, so how would I account for the status bar while having the buttons be half of the screen - the status bar?

Thanks for the help (if there is any),
James.

Comment: So if I am right your are trying to have 2 same buttons with top status bar?

Comment: @0ndre_ correct, assuming you mean 2 buttons of the same height and a status bar.

Comment: do you want the buttons to appear underneath the status bar? or do you want the white space at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the top spacing constraint for your top button set as relative to the "Top Layout Guide", which directly under the status bar in your view.

If you give that constraint a constant of -20 (the height of the status bar), it will move the buttons up. Alternatively, you can set the top constraint to be relative to the container margin instead of the top layout guide. This will ignore the status bar.

If you want to keep the spacing with the status bar, simply set the constant on each button's proportional height constraint to be -10. You can leave the proportion as .5 - the constant will be applied separately.

Comment: Cheers mate. I wanted to keep the spacing with the status bar so I used that -10 constant technique on both buttons and it worked like a charm. Much appreciated, **+1**

Answer (score 1):

So what should work is:

Set up your constrains similar to this UI (equal widths and heights)

[image]

And put `UIView` on the top.(Height of this view should be 20).
Let me know if it helped you :) (So I can improve my answer)

Comment: I'll still give you a **+1** because your answer is a good one, but I didn't need to add a UIView when there's only 2 buttons in the View Controller. Much appreciated for the help, but just offset the button's height by -10. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JammehCow  and happy coding :)